# Eventbrite authentication using OAuth2.0 Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, eventbrite

Iam creating an application where I am trying to authentivate a user with eventbrite. With reference of [doc](https://github.com/ryanjarvinen/Eventbrite.jquery.js/blob/master/OAUTH2-README.md) I include the javascript in my application and it generates a **CONNECT WITH EVENTBRITE** link in my app.

When I click this button It takes me to the url:

https://www.eventbrite.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx

(Here client id is the eventbrite app key of my application.)

When the user *ALLOWS* the application to access the evenbrite account it redirects me to my application with the following url:

```
http://localhost:3000/#token_type=Bearer&access_token=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

I want the **access token** in the url to access a user's information. I tried to parse url using **URI**. But I didn't find it the best way to do so.. Can anyone please tell me a good solution to extract the **access_token** from the above url.

Answer (score 1):

For [server-side OAuth2.0](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/authentication/oauth2/#server-side), I'd use response_type=code in your initial URL:

```
https://www.eventbrite.com/oauth/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

To find the access_code, grab the 'code' parameter from the querystring:

```
require 'uri'
uri = URI("http://localhost:3000/?code=XVYMCZOHM4D2GBXTJZG6")
access_code = uri.query.split('&')[0].split('=')[1]
```

The next step is to make a server-side POST to https://www.eventbrite.com/oauth/token with the temporary access_code, your client_secret, and a few other details (outlined here: http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/authentication/oauth2/)

```
code=THE_USERS_AUTH_CODE&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET&client_id=YOUR_API_KEY&grant_type=authorization_code
```

The user's access_token should be available in the POST response.

Comment: This is how I am making post request.  uri=URI('http://www.eventbrite.com/oauth/token')
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, 'code' => code, 'client_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx','client_id' =>'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx','grant_type' => 'authorization_code' ). I am getting 302 response code ie redirection and its redirecting to base url ie https://www.eventbrite.com/oauth/token