# Rails Customize the eventbrite omniauth callback url

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth, eventbrite

I am using **eventbrite omniauth** to authenticate the user. With reference to https://github.com/k504866430/omniauth-eventbrite I included the gem and created a file *omniauth.rb* file as:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :eventbrite, ENV['EVENTBRITE_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['EVENTBRITE_CLIENT_SECRET']
end
```

On the show page of each event there is link to **Authenticate with eventbrite**.

*events/24*

```
 = link_to "Authenticate with Eventbrite", "/auth/eventbrite"
```

When the user allows to access I want the callback url to redirect to same event page.

Thus I need to know how to pass the **event_id** in params so that the application can return to the same event page and how should the **callback url** be defined in *routes.rb* file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventbrite's [OAuth2.0 implementation](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/authentication/oauth2/) does not allow you to define the OAuth callback URL as a querystring parameter.  This callback_url can only be defined by configuring your [Eventbrite application key](http://www.eventbrite.com/api/key/)'s 'redirect_uri' setting.

Pass-through of custom querystring parameters (such as an event_id) is also not supported.
Besides, you'll need to do [a bit of follow-up work AFTER the user arrives back on your site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365331/eventbrite-authentication-using-oauth2-0-rails).

If you need to redirect a user [after they return to your website](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/workflows/#authorization), I would consider stashing the 'redirect_url' (and possibly the event_id as well) in the user's browser session or another data store.
Setting up a single landing page (to match your redirect_uri) should allow you to complete the OAuth2.0 handshake before sending the user on to a url of your choice.